# Batchfile cannot find specified path, but path clearly exists

Tags: batch-file, cmd

### Context

I am sharing a file via network from one machine to another on Windows 11 (both machines). The file path from the perspective of the machine this has been shared to is:

```
\\NTWRK-1\shared\logfile.log
```

In the same folder there is a simple batchfile, which is designed to open the file once per second and print the first line. The batchfile path is:

```
\\NTWRK-1\shared\auto_refresh.bat
```

This is the content of the batchfile:

```
# Auto-Refresh logfile on caller machine
set root=%~dp0
set logfile=logfile.log

:loop
rem Refresh..

for /f %%a in (%root%%logfile%) do (
  echo %%a
  exit /b
)

timeout /t 1
goto loop
```

### Problem statement

When I launch the batchfile on the machine the file has been shared to, I am receiving the following error message:

```
The system cannot find the file \\NTWRK-1\shared\logfile.log.
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me, because the file exists. If I copy the path `\\NTWRK-1\shared\logfile.log` directly from the console output into an explorer window, it then opens the file in an editor.

### Attempted solutions

My ideas on what to do are running out. I tried:

- Wrapping the path into the variables `root` and `logfile` to avoid possible delimiter issues
- Adding `"usebackq delims=|"` to the loop declaration
- Running the batchfile from terminal via `./auto_refresh.bat` / `start ./auto_refresh.bat`
- Ran batchfile both as Admin and as a regular user

I am likely missing something very obvious right in front of me.

Comment: Batch sometimes has trouble with UNC paths. Can you `pushd \\NTWRK-1\shared\` in the script and see if you can access the file that way?

Comment: I have done that, `pushd` does not throw an error given the provided network is correct, but problem persists, sadly.

Comment: Pick an unused drive letter (for example, Q) and `NET USE Q: \\NTWRK-1\SHARED`, then `PUSHD Q:` and see if the file works then.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - `pushd` should mount the network share as a drive automatically if there is a letter available

Comment: @SomethingDark - Yes, that's what's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd), but some testing seems to result in "...maybe. If Windows feels like it."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin This seems to have some effect. While it tells me that the local device name is already in use when running the script more than once, the file was still read correctly when attempting it this way.

Comment: Put `root` and `logfile` variables in cmd and try to calling them